# MySQL LOAD binary data "warning(s): 1366 Incorrect integer value"

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, load

In MYSQL 6.3 on my local Mac, I created a database with the following table, among many others:

```
CREATE TABLE DIVISIONS
   (DIVISION                TINYINT            NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION             VARCHAR(31)        NULL);
```

Now I am trying to load data from a file which the person who gave the file to me says it is binary and of fixed length.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE '/Users/.../dat/div.dat' INTO TABLE `DIVISIONS` (@var1, @var2)
SET DIVISION = SUBSTR(@var1,0,1), DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(@var2,1,31);

0  NULL
```

So then I tried a few variations and have the same error.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE '/Users/.../dat/div.dat' INTO TABLE `DIVISIONS` (@var1)
SET DIVISION = SUBSTR(@var1,0,1), DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(@var1,1,31);
```

Here is the pattern of results:

```
0   NULL           ... DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(@var2,1,31);
0                  ... DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(@var1,0,31);
0   Furniture      ... DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(@var1,1,31);
0   Furniture      ... DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(@var1,2,31);
0   urniture       ... DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(@var1,3,31);
0   rniture        ... DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(@var1,4,31);
```

Three questions:

First, how do I return the values for the next row?

Second, why do I get NULL when I try to reference @var2?

Third, just curious, but why does ...@var1,1... return the same as ...@var1,2...?

Comment: The following code is returning the correct results, so I will just put this into a WHILE loop.

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL
      INFILE '/Users/.../dat/div.dat' INTO TABLE `DIVISIONS` (@var1, @var2)
      SET DIVISION = SUBSTR(@var1,0,1), DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(@var1,2,32);  
    LOAD DATA LOCAL
      INFILE '/Users/.../dat/div.dat' INTO TABLE `DIVISIONS` (@var1, @var2)
      SET DIVISION = SUBSTR(@var1,33,1), DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(@var1,34,65);
    LOAD DATA LOCAL
      INFILE '/Users/.../dat/div.dat' INTO TABLE `DIVISIONS` (@var1, @var2)
      SET DIVISION = SUBSTR(@var1,66,1), DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(@var1,67,98);